# Escaping Characters from MySQL from PHP Framework

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if when using the database library in Codeigniter there was a way to automatically escape all the inputs to prevent injection. I know I can use mysql_real_escape_string() to do it, but I wondered it this was already setup to do this automatically, if not are there any frameworks that have this included?

Thanks!

Comment: Use prepared statements so you can say bye bye to mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: Forgive me, By prepared statements do you mean a function which cleanses all the variables and then puts them in the db?

Comment: No, he means [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: As Pete said any MVC framework should have it's own functions for interfacing with your db and take care of the repetitive stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use prepared statements, you can simply use query bindings with CodeIgniter.

```
$query = 'SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE name = ?';
$bind = array('Jake');
$this->db->query($query, $bind);
```

[More info found here.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html)

Answer (score 1):

Right, pretty [much](http://codeigniter.com/) [all](http://cakephp.org) [frameworks](http://framework.zend.com) that implement any sort of database abstraction/ORM layer will automatically `mysql_real_espace` your queries. If you don't want to use an entire framework, consider a generic ORM library like [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/). Alternatively, look into [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you for your response, with a default installation of CodeIgniter, I added in the database library and I can insert quotes into a text input which then is sent to an Update query (using the database helper) and it results in a syntax error. So perhaps there is further configuration with CodeIgniter?

Comment: @Pete Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. From your question I thought you were already familiar with CodeIgniter and are looking for ORM libraries like the one CI uses, which *doesn't* require any manual escaping...? Personally I have no experience with CI, so I can't tell you any specifics about it.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP runs all model queries through its own methods, if you use the model methods it automatically sanitizes any data passed to the query for you. i.e

```
$options['conditions'] = array('Product.status'=>$status);
$this->Product->find('first',$options);
```